# Ireport 4.0.2 band layout multiple column headers and footers

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible in Ireport to have a band layout like the one below without using subreport? Or is there any other workaround. I tried to use subreport but unfortunately I cannot solve my issue. These have separate queries and I use php to fill in data to each details. Please help me.

```
Column Header 1
   Detail 1
Column Footer 1

Column Header 2
   Detail 2
Column Footer 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ireport 4.0.2 set subreport data using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019330/ireport-4-0-2-set-subreport-data-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Table elements in your report. You can use there the same dataset too.